# Select all with checkbox in jqgrid with virtual scroll possible?

Tags: jqgrid, scroll

I have a checkbox column in my jqgrid and am using datatype local, and scroll=1 to get (dynamic page turning e.g. virtual scroll) and a numRows value.

When I click the header checkbox to select all the rows it's not selecting any that aren't within what's visible . Is there a way to set jqgrid to support click on checkbox header to select all the data not just the part that is partially shown?

Comment: You found a solution for this? If so, kindly post!

Answer (score 0):

`$("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');` will return an array of objects which is all the data (every page) from your grid.
These objects have `_id_` as their attribute. You can now loop through this array and use the `setSelection` method to select all of the rows using the `_id_`.

Example:

```
var all_data = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
for(var i=0; i<all_data.length; i++){
$("#grid").setSelection(all_data[i]._id_);
}
```